# replace last array elements to zero java

Tags: java, arrays

So, I made an A and B arrays from 15 and 5 int numbers, next I need to change the last 5 numbers to zeros (elements from A[10] to A[14]) and afterwards input integer K:

- If the number K ranging from zero to 9, then array element A value of the element A [0] to A [9]
  calculate using the expression A [i] = i*K, but the array B elements calculate using the expression:
  B [i] = 10 * (i + 1) * K.
- If the number K is negative or greater than 9, then assign a variable K =5 and fill the first ten A array elements with arbitrary integers from the range from 0 to 50, but with an array of B arbitrary integers from the range between 50 and 100.
  Anyway, now I have [this][1]

Can anyone help me a little bit with the first bullet list item? I'm a bit stuck here in my uni work. I know this shouldn't be difficult but after trying to fill the first ten A array elements with arbitrary integers i got stuck..

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ld3161RDB155
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int A[] = new int[15];
    int B[] = new int[5];
    int K, i;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("161RDB155");
    System.out.print("K=");
    try
    {
      K = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.out.println("input-output error");
      return;
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    if (K < 0 && K > 9)
    {
      K = 5;
      i = 0;
      do
      {
        A[i] = r.nextInt(51);
        i++;
      }
      while (i < 10);

      i = 0;
      do
      {
        B[i] = r.nextInt(50) + 50;
        i++;
      }
      while (i < 5);
    }

    else
    {
      i = 0;
      do
      {
        A[i] = i * K;
        i++;
      }
      while (i < 10);

      i = 0;
      do
      {
        B[i] = 10 * (i + 1) * K;
        i++;
      }
      while (i < 5);
    }

    System.out.println("A:");
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(A[i] + "\t");
      if (i == 14)
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("B:");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(B[i] + "\t");
      if (i == 4)
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to change the values of `A` and `B`.

Comment: @bradimus how to do it?

Comment: SO is neither a code writing service nor a replacement for basic tutorials. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: For the first bullet, should *every* element of A and B be calcuated that way? If that is the case, I believe you are best off with an oldfashioned for loop: `for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {` … `}`. For changing a value in the array, use the formulas in the question, only remember to end each statement with a semicolon, that’s all.

Comment: @OleV.V.  So I tried to make the first part of the program, take a look at the first post

Answer (score 1):

Your code seemed to be on track.

Replacing your do-while loops makes it more readable.

Most importantly your line  `if (K < 0 && K > 9)` needs to be an `or` statement `||'.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ld3161RDB155
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int a[] = new int[15];
    int b[] = new int[5];
    int k;
    Random r = new Random();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("161RDB155");
    System.out.print("K=");
    try
    {
      k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.out.println("input-output error");
      return;
    }

    if (k < 0 || k > 9)
    {
      k = 5;

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        a[i] = r.nextInt(51);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
        b[i] = r.nextInt(51) + 50;
      }
    }

    else
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        a[i] = i * k;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
        b[i] = 10 * (i + 1) * k;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("A:" + (Arrays.toString(a)));

    System.out.println("B:" + (Arrays.toString(b)));
  }
}
```